# Tkinter's checkbutton makes checkmark invisible after changing background color

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using `tkinter` to create a simple GUI with python. I wanted to change the background and foreground color of a `Checkbutton` and while that works, it makes the checkmark itself invisible. It still works, tested with a simple function, but I seem to miss something. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def check1Clicked():
    if var1.get():
        print("clicked")
    else:
        print("not clicked")


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")

var1 = tk.IntVar()
c1   = tk.Checkbutton(root, text="bla", variable=var1,
         onvalue=1, offvalue=0,
         bg="red",fg="white",
         command=check1Clicked
         )
# use "place" to easily center widget
c1.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

root.mainloop()
```

Any suggestions what I am missing would be greatly appreciated!

The versions I am using:

```
python:  3.8.10
tkinter: 8.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be caused by `fg='white'`, because the check mark matches the foreground color. Ergo, when the box is checked, the checkmark is white on a white background.

To alleviate this, you can either

- Change to `fg=black` (or omit it entirely since black is the default), but this has the effect of making your text black as well

or

- Change the background color of the checkbox itself with `selectcolor=black`, so the checkmark will appear as white on a black background (you could really use any color here, just know that the box will use the `selectcolor` and the check mark will use the `fg` color)

Neither of these is a perfect solution, unfortunately, but they will work.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed works as a, well workaround. Might it be possible to use the font options and apply a color to the font that way...?

Comment: AFAIK, the `Font` class doesn't accept a parameter for color. You could look into using `ttk.Checkbutton` instead - then maybe you'll have more options open to you via `ttk.Style`

Comment: Ah, nice idea, of course, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! Sorry there's no better out-of-the-box option